# Gridview: Cant remove borders

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview inside a GridView cell as you can see on the image. I am trying to remove the 2 horizontal lines that are i believe are borders below the word has and beyond the word next.

[image]

```
 foreach (TableCell tc in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-bottom-style:none";
            tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-width:0px";
            tc.Attributes["style"] = "border-top-style:none";
        }
```

But it doesnt works. Any Help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the following property to your GridView

```
GridLines="None"
```

This should remove all the borders.